# use component without MatDialog, MatDialogRef<SomeComponent>

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-material2

I have a function that opens a MatDialog with a component called 'NoteFormComponent' it looks like this

```
  openForm() {
    let dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();
    dialogConfig.autoFocus = true;
    dialogConfig.width = "95%";
    dialogConfig.panelClass = "form-dialog";
    dialogConfig.scrollStrategy = new NoopScrollStrategy();

    this.dialog.open(NoteFormComponent, dialogConfig).beforeClose().subscribe(() => this.getNotes());
  }
```

I pops up a modal containing the 'NoteFormComponent'.
**So WHAT is the problem?**

The problem is that I want to **use 'NoteFormComponent' without a MatDialog**, but in order to use it with the MatDialog I had to inject a reference in the component's constructor like this

```
  constructor(
    private noteService : NoteService, 
    private productService : ProductService,
    private categoryService : CategoryService,
    private clientService : ClientService,
    private notification : NotificationService,
    private dialogRef : MatDialogRef<NoteFormComponent>, /*This Reference*/
    private loader : LoaderService,
    private sessionService : SessionService,
    private securityBlockerService : SecurityBlockerService,
    private dialog : MatDialog,
    private dialogService : DialogService
  ) { }
```

And if I try to use the component with the template selector '' it throws an error that **there is no provider for MatDialogRef**, the only thing that comes to my mind is create a copy of the 'NoteFormComponent' but without the MatDialogRef injector in the constructor.

Is there anyway to solve or work around this problem?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the `@Optional()` decorator when injecting the MatDialogRef in constructor ([Reference](https://angular.io/api/core/Optional)):

```js
constructor(
    ...
    @Optional() private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<NoteFormComponent>,
    ...
) { ... }
```

By doing this, you can consume the `NoteFormComponent` in the normal way, without using MatDialog.

Comment: Thank you! it's exactly what I needed

Comment: Do you think angular need a feature like : instead of using `@Optional() private dialogRef: <..>`, use `private dialogRef?: <..>` with the same behaviour?

Comment: A cleaner way of typing this: `@Optional() private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<NoteFormComponent> | null`.